# Scrapy-TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments error

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, typeerror

I am new in Python and i am following the tutorial and i got this error.

When i run scrapy it says typeerror:cannot mix str and non-str arguments Can you help me please

Thank you in advance.

```
class ForRentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'for_rent'
allowed_domains = ['www.laforet.com/']
start_urls = ['https://www.laforet.com/louer/rechercher']

def parse(self, response):
    houses = response.xpath("//div[@class='list-item mb-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3']/div/a")

    for house in houses:
        title = house.xpath(".//div[@class='d-flex justify-content-between']/h4/text()").get(),
        link = response.urljoin(house.xpath(".//@href").get()),
        metre = house.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='property-card__infos']/div/span/text())").get(),
        room = house.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='property-card__infos']/div/span[2]/text())").get(),
        price = house.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[@class='property-card__infos']/span/text())").get()

        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_house, meta={'house_title': title, 'house_metrekare': metre, 'house_room': room, 'house_price': price})

def parse_house(self, response):
    title = response.request.meta['house_title']
    metre = response.request.meta['house_metrekare']
    room = response.request.meta['house_room']
    price = response.request.meta['house_price']
    infos = response.xpath("//div[@class='property-content__description mb-4']")

    for info in infos:
        house_info = info.xpath(".//div[@class='mb-2']/text()").get()

        yield{
            'house_title': title,
            'house_metrekare': metre,
            'house_room': room,
            'house_price': price,
            'info': house_info

        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the **full text** of the error or traceback you're getting, as *formatted text*. Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please include you execution logs in this type of questions, as they help us to understand the issue.

The problem in your code is that you are passing a tuple in the variable `link`, when it should be a string. The reason for that is that you are adding a comma at the end of the variable definition, for no apparent reason.

```
    link = response.urljoin(house.xpath(".//@href").get()),
```

Python interprets this as a tuple of a single value. Removing the `,` at the end of the line will solve your problem.

There are other lines in your code doing the same, if you don't want those variables to be tuples you should remove the `,` at the end of their lines as well. They won't cause an issue though, as they are not used in the request method.